# Python nonlocal statement in a class definition

Tags: python, class, python-3.x, python-nonlocal

I'm trying to perform some analysis of scope in Python 3 source code and I'm stuck with how the nonlocal statement statement works inside a class definition.

As I understand it, the class definition executes its body inside a new namespace (call it dict) and binds the class name to the result of type(name, bases, dict). Nonlocal x should work as long as it refers to a variable that is bound somewhere in the enclosing non-local scope.

From this I expect the following code to compile and run:

```
class A:
    v = 1
    class B:
        nonlocal v
        v = 2
```

but this fails with

```
SyntaxError: no binding for nonlocal 'v' found
```

while the following code runs perfectly

```
def A():
    v = 1
    class B:
        nonlocal v
        v = 2
```

Can anyone explain the difference here between the closure of the function definition and the class definition?

Comment: More research - in the last code sample, locals() in A is {v:1}, whereas inside B it is {v:2, '`__module__`':'`__main__`', '`__locals__`':{...}}

Comment: This follows directly from the scoping rules; `class` doesn't create a scope, so it can't create an enclosing scope, so it can't create an enclosing scope that is subsequently accessed via `nonlocal`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Lexical scoping applies only to function namespaces, otherwise methods defined inside a class would be able to "see" the class level attributes (which is by design - those attributes must instead be accessed as attributes of `self` inside the method).

The same limitations that cause the class level variables to be skipped over by references from methods also keep the `nonlocal` keyword from working its magic. (`global` does work though, since that doesn't rely on the lexical scoping machinery)

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense. I had assumed there was some very basic form of stack that would work the same for every level. Noticing the symtable module docs changed my mind but I didn't really understand what was going on or why until your answer.

Answer (score 5):

Python handles class and function definitions rather differently. For example, your `A.v` is not a variable of A but rather an attribute of it. The namespace created by a class is not, therefore, a scope. I am not surprised that `nonlocal` does not work as you're trying to use it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So the function scope is created when it is run rather than when it's defined. As the body of the class definition is, I assume, executed immediately in a different namespace, does this not create a scope just for the duration of this execution? - I'm wondering if this is happening for the same reason an inner class can't access the attributes of an outer class...

Comment: It does create a temporary scope, but it's a different *kind* of scope. The compiler uses different rules in deciding which attributes are visible (both for reference from inner scopes and for writing to outer scopes).